# spring amqp ReplyRequiredException

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp, qpid

I have a request/reply implemented using spring integration and amqp. The requests may take long time to process (they may take even an hour for some cases) , for some reason the client throws exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyRequiredException: No reply produced by handler 'client', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true.
```

My client config is below.

```
 <int-amqp:outbound-gateway
        id="client"
        request-channel="in"
        reply-channel="res"
        exchange-name="reportingServer"
        routing-key-expression="'report.req.'+headers.id"
        amqp-template="amqpTemplate" requires-reply="true">
        </int-amqp:outbound-gateway>
```

I believe reply-timeout default value is -1, means wait indefinitely, but not sure why its not working, any help would be appreciated.

Also are there any known issues with implementing such long waiting operations in amqp or it should be just fine?

Thank You

Comment: The timeout is configured at amqpTemplate and working without any issues. Though i will still like to know if there any concerns around waiting for too long or a any other configuration required, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be fine as long as you don't have too many concurrent requests - it won't scale very well if you have gazillions of threads hanging waiting for a reply.

If you need to scale it, you could devise an asynchronous equivalent with a pair of outbound and inbound adapters, but it's a little more involved than using a gateway and the actual implementation will depend on the rest of your flow. Essentially you'll have to set up the `replyTo` header to cause the reply to come to the inbound adapter.

If you have a simple `<gateway/>` upstream of the AMQP gateway, you'll need to be sure that the `replyChannel` header is not lost. [See `Header Channel Registry` in this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#header-enricher).

Comment: Hi Gary thanks, could you please help to understand how it is different to have a separate inbound adapter to get the response verses reply-channel in a outbound-gateway. Will not an inbound adapter have a socket opened (hence a thread) to receive the response?

Comment: Yes, but the reply needs to be correlated to the request - which happens automatically in the gateway and you have to do it "manually" when using 2 separate async endpoints; there will be one thread (by default) to handle all the replies rather than hanging a thread for each reply. Like I said, I'd need to see more of your flow to provide concrete advice if you expect to have many concurrent requests in process.